# Why is my skew via -ms-filter matrix not being applied in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, skew

I've been building a site through Chrome/Firefox, and now that I look at it on IE, it's very broken.  I anticipated this, but fixing it is proving a lot more difficult than I thought.

The main issue is that my site uses a number of skewed elements (they're used as parallelograms), and that skew is not being applied on IE.  These divs are given the class "parallelogram", and so in my code I've written:

```
div.parallelogram { position:absolute; top:0; right:25%; z-index:20; height:100%;
                    width:20%; margin:0;
                    background-color:#000; color:inherit;
                    -moz-transform:skew(-20deg);
                    -o-transform:skew(-20deg);
                    -webkit-transform:skew(-20deg);
                    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.3, M12=1.3,
                      M21=0.7, M22=0, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; }
```

Yes, I'm missing the "filter:" tag, but from what I've read, that tag is only needed for IE7 or less.  I want to get it working on at least one version of IE, then I can consider the rest!

So when I look at this code using Chrome, the -ms-filter tag is there and crossed out.  On IE, it doesn't even appear.  I've copied code many times from code generators online, but it's still not working!  Any ideas?

[Here's a page](http://andrewbusch.com.au/projects/test) with this issue.  I know the links aren't working, I intentionally broke them.

UPDATE: Thanks to Teemu, I applied -ms-transform, so I can now get the skew working on >=IE9.  I still would like to support at least IE8.

Comment: `-ms-transform: skew(-20deg);` works in IE>=9.

Comment: Nice one, I've updated that.  I still need to get it working for at least IE8 though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you are using IE9 or IE10 in testing mode changing with "F12" key the rendered version of IE. The IE filter tag does not work to check if your filter is working in IE7 you need a native version of IE7, and the same to all other versions.